# Packer build with Ubuntu 20.4 and autoinstall with vSphere 7.0

Tags: vmware-vsphere, ubuntu-20.04, packer

I am trying to build a packer image with packer 1.8.1 and Ubuntu 20.4

My HCL manifest is correct but I always get the prompt with " Continue with Autoinstall ? Add autoinstall in kernel command line to avoid this"

I tried many configurations without any effects. Does anyone have a tip ?

Here is my hcl manifest and my user-data

```
source "vsphere-iso" "example" {
  CPUs                 = 4
  RAM                  = 4096
  RAM_reserve_all      = true
  boot_command         = [
                          "<enter><wait><wait><enter><wait><f6><esc><wait> ",
                          "autoinstall net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0 ip=dhcp ipv6.disable=1 ds=nocloud;",
                          "<wait><enter>"
                         ]
  disk_controller_type = ["pvscsi"]
  guest_os_type        = "ubuntu64Guest"
  host                 = "esx6.maquette.lan"
  insecure_connection  = true
  iso_paths            = ["[DT1_ESX6] ISO/ubuntu-20.04.4-live-server-amd64.iso"]
  cd_files = ["./meta-data", "./user-data"]
  cd_label = "cidata"
  network_adapters {
    network_card = "vmxnet3"
    network = "PG_WINDOWS-SRV_VL8"
  }
  ssh_password = "ubuntu"
  ssh_username = "ubuntu"
  ssh_timeout = "180m"
  disable_shutdown = true
  shutdown_timeout = "180m"
  storage {
    disk_size             = 55000
    disk_thin_provisioned = true
  }
  username            = "<username>"
  vcenter_server      = "vcenter.lan"
  password            = "<password>"
```

And the user-date used for ubuntu autoinstall:

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  early-commands:
    - sudo systemctl stop ssh
    - echo "yes"
  locale: en_US.UTF-8
  keyboard:
    layout: fr
    variant: us
  packages: [open-vm-tools, openssh-server, chrony, curl, vim, ifupdown, unzip,  gnupg2, software-properties-common, apt-transport-https, ca-certificates, lsb-release]
  identity:
    hostname: epachard
    password: '$6$wdAcoXrU039hKYPd$508Qvbe7ObUnxoj15DRCkzC3qO7edjH0VV7BPNRDYK4QR8ofJaEEF2heacn0QgD.f8pO8SNp83XNdWG6tocBM1'
    username: ubuntu
  ssh:
    install-server: yes
  network:
    network:
      version: 2
      ethernets:
        ens192: {dhcp4: true, dhcp-identifier: mac}
  apt:
    preserve_sources_list: false
    primary:
        - arches: [amd64]
          uri: "http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu"
        - arches: [default]
          uri: "http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports"
    geoip: true
  storage:
  config:
  - grub_device: true
    id: disk-sda
    name: ''
    path: /dev/sda
    preserve: false
    ptable: gpt
    type: disk
    wipe: superblock
  - device: disk-sda
    flag: bios_grub
    grub_device: false
    id: partition-0
    number: 1
    preserve: false
    size: 1048576
    type: partition
  - device: disk-sda
    flag: ''
    grub_device: false
    id: partition-1
    number: 2
    preserve: false
    size: 1073741824
    type: partition
    wipe: superblock
  - fstype: xfs
    id: format-2
    preserve: false
    type: format
    volume: partition-1
  - device: disk-sda
    flag: ''
    grub_device: false
    id: partition-3
    number: 3
    preserve: false
    size: 56908316672
    type: partition
    wipe: superblock
  - devices:
    - partition-3
    id: lvm_volgroup-1
    name: vg0
    preserve: false
    type: lvm_volgroup
  - id: lvm_partition-1
    name: lv_root
    preserve: false
    size: 10737418240B
    type: lvm_partition
    volgroup: lvm_volgroup-1
    wipe: superblock
  - fstype: xfs
    id: format-3
    preserve: false
    type: format
    volume: lvm_partition-1
  - device: format-3
    id: mount-3
    path: /
    type: mount
  - id: lvm_partition-2
    name: lv_home
    preserve: false
    size: 1073741824B
    type: lvm_partition
    volgroup: lvm_volgroup-1
    wipe: superblock
  - fstype: xfs
    id: format-4
    preserve: false
    type: format
    volume: lvm_partition-2
  - device: format-4
    id: mount-4
    path: /home
    type: mount
  - id: lvm_partition-3
    name: lv_tmp
    preserve: false
    size: 4294967296B
    type: lvm_partition
    volgroup: lvm_volgroup-1
    wipe: superblock
  - fstype: xfs
    id: format-5
    preserve: false
    type: format
    volume: lvm_partition-3
  - device: format-5
    id: mount-5
    path: /tmp
    type: mount
  - id: lvm_partition-4
    name: lv_var
    preserve: false
    size: 3221225472B
    type: lvm_partition
    volgroup: lvm_volgroup-1
    wipe: superblock
  - fstype: xfs
    id: format-6
    preserve: false
    type: format
    volume: lvm_partition-4
  - device: format-6
    id: mount-6
    path: /var
    type: mount
  - id: lvm_partition-5
    name: lv_var_log
    preserve: false
    size: 4294967296B
    type: lvm_partition
    volgroup: lvm_volgroup-1
    wipe: superblock
  - fstype: xfs
    id: format-7
    preserve: false
    type: format
    volume: lvm_partition-5
  - device: format-7
    id: mount-7
    path: /var/log
    type: mount
  - id: lvm_partition-6
    name: lv_var_log_audit
    preserve: false
    size: 2147483648B
    type: lvm_partition
    volgroup: lvm_volgroup-1
    wipe: superblock
  - fstype: xfs
    id: format-8
    preserve: false
    type: format
    volume: lvm_partition-6
  - device: format-8
    id: mount-8
    path: /var/log/audit
    type: mount
  - id: lvm_partition-7
    name: lv_var_tmp
    preserve: false
    size: 1073741824B
    type: lvm_partition
    volgroup: lvm_volgroup-1
    wipe: superblock
  - fstype: xfs
    id: format-9
    preserve: false
    type: format
    volume: lvm_partition-7
  - device: format-9
    id: mount-9
    path: /var/tmp
    type: mount
  - id: lvm_partition-8
    name: lv_opt
    preserve: false
    size: 2147483648B
    type: lvm_partition
    volgroup: lvm_volgroup-1
    wipe: superblock
  - fstype: xfs
    id: format-10
    preserve: false
    type: format
    volume: lvm_partition-8
  - device: format-10
    id: mount-10
    path: /opt
    type: mount
  - id: lvm_partition-9
    name: lv_swap
    preserve: false
    size: 2147483648B
    type: lvm_partition
    volgroup: lvm_volgroup-1
    wipe: superblock
  - fstype: swap
    id: format-11
    preserve: false
    type: format
    volume: lvm_partition-9
  - device: format-11
    id: mount-11
    path: ''
    type: mount
  - device: format-2
    id: mount-2
    path: /boot
    type: mount
  late-commands:
    - sed -i 's/^#*\(send dhcp-client-identifier\).*$/\1 = hardware;/' /target/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Why has this got the 'vSphere' tag in it?

Comment: because it is used with vSphere

Comment: What bearing does that have on the problem?

Comment: It is only because it is part of the ecosystem of the problem. vSphere tag can be removed if needed

Comment: Anyway, my problem is solved but i cannot answer the question